# MPAndroidChart BarChart with day as x labels

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am creating a bar chart using MPAndroidChart. It should display a daily amount with day-of-week on the X axis, and display only the five most recent days.

For example, the first five xlabels for April 26-30 would be: 0426,0427,0428,0429,0430.

The plot displays properly, but where the month changes there is a huge gap (e.g., in between 0430 and 0501).

I want the data to be close together even when the month changes.

Comment: Can you share more details about what solutions you've tried so far, perhaps with some example code?

Comment: hi this has been answered by Sahil. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your x-axis labels are MMDD, where the first 2 digits represent the numeric month, and the last 2 digits represent the day of the month. Instead, you should make your x-axis labels range from 0 to 364, where the number represents the number of days since the start of the year. This way, April 30 will be encoded as 120, and May 1 will be encoded as 121. This will remove gaps on month-changes, since the x-axis will only increment by 1.

Here is some code to get the number of days since start of the year for the last five days:

```
int[] days = new int[5];
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
for (int i = days.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    days[i] = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect idea thank you very much it is working now. I will have the same problem when the year changes though. So the last x will be 364 but when the year changes it starts with 1 so there will have a huge gap on those dates. Anyway i will think of a solution. I am very new to programming appreciate your help.